# Where is the github page repo?

Tags: github, github-pages

According to the [guide of github page](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/), when a github page is create, we should be able to find the repo on github.com, with the following rule: if we have username.github.io, then we can find the repo in github.com/username.

However, sometimes, I can't find the repo with the rule above. I would like to know if there is another way to host a github page, or maybe the username.github.io can be private but the website is public ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your example, has `username.github.io` but don't see `github.com/username`

Comment: For example, http://paldhous.github.io/ucb/2016/dataviz/index.html, so I should find the repo paldhous.github.io, on https://github.com/paldhous, no?

Comment: Let see: 4 contributions in private repositories, try to scroll down. This user  paid fee for GitHub, you can see private activities. repository for GitHub pages user is private repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see repository, It's no necessary to mean repository isn't exist, it is private repository.

GitHub page for user, projects

[image]

[image]

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/